# IP rules in sudoers file don't work

Tags: ssh, sudo

I have two servers, a and b. When I login to a, then ssh to b, I don't want to enter password for sudo commands.

On b, I set if the host is 172.25.9.13, sudo requires no password.

```
gqqnbig@b:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers.d/cluster-create-user
%sudo 172.25.9.13=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
gqqnbig@b:~$ sudo cat /etc/sudoers
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/snap/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Limit members of group sudo to execute any command, except
test ALL=ALL, !/bin/su

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

Now I log in to a, make sure the IP of a is 172.25.9.13. Then I ssh to b. However, sudo on b still requires password.

```
gqqnbig@a:~$ ifconfig
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.25.9.13  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.25.9.255
        inet6 fe80::3648:edff:fef9:9c1c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 34:48:ed:f9:9c:1c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 492366  bytes 127428889 (127.4 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 212004  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 133728  bytes 21062341 (21.0 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 33

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2865  bytes 266771 (266.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2865  bytes 266771 (266.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0


gqqnbig@a:~$ ssh b
...
Last login: Tue Mar  2 11:15:57 2021 from 172.28.80.67
gqqnbig@b:~$ sudo mkdir
[sudo] password for gqqnbig:
```

Why doesn't the IP rule work? How do I debug it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Host is the system where the `sudo` command is run. It has nothing to do with any remote system you might be connecting from (about which `sudo` doesn't know anything in the first place). A Host spec of `172.25.9.13` matches if one of `b`'s interfaces has `172.25.9.13` as the IP.

(This is probably useful in a setup where the same `sudoers` file is shared across multiple systems.)